# Check jquery unobtrusive validation is true by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, unobtrusive-validation

I use MVC 3 Model Validation Attributes and jquery unobtrusive to show validation error message also use the script when form submitted return a confirm. So I need to check if the all fields are valid then return Confirm: some thing like the following pseudo-script:

```
$('div.FormNeedConfirm form').submit(function () {
    if ($(this).validate() == true) {
        var Message = $('#FormConfirmMessage').val();
        return confirm(Message);
    }
});
```

But I don't know what exactly should be in the if condition. What is your suggestion?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
if ($(this).valid()) {

    var Message = $('#FormConfirmMessage').val();
    return confirm(Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`if ($(this).validate() = true)  // your if condition should be "==".`
change to like this

```
if ($(this).validate() == true)
```

Comment: That's not worked I just add that script as a simple I think the condition is wrong at all